# SQL Server service not accepting connections

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, service

I am having a strange problem that happens randomly on a server.  Some mornings, our client will call in and say their website is not working with the following error message:

> The underlying provider failed on Open.

The temporary fix I found for this was to manually go in and restart the SQL Server service.  Once this is done it works just fine until the next random time it happens.  So my question is, does anyone know what exactly is happening?  If so, how can I prevent this in the future?

I have tried searching everywhere for this with the only explanation saying that updates were being applied to the service and it wasn't restarted properly.  But I couldn't find any fixes. Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you see in the ERRORLOG for the Sql Server?

Comment: There is a lot of 'Login failed for user' and before that there is a 'FCB::Open failed: could not open file (LDF file) for the file number 2.  OS error: 32( The process cannot access the file because it's being used by another process)'

Comment: Do you have a virus scanner that's running on that machine? You may want to add *.mdf / *.ndf / *.ldf files to the exclusions list.

Comment: I do not have a virus scanner running, BUT this is a GoDaddy server that runs some Go Daddy Protection Site Scanner.  But this has happened before that scanner was setup also

Comment: Can you use a program like ProcessExplorer whenever it's happening to see what program is holding a lock on the LDF file?

Answer (score 0):

This error:

```
'FCB::Open failed: could not open file (LDF file) for the file number 2. OS error: 32( The process cannot access the file because it's being used by another process)
```

is quite troubling and should not be occurring, unless you just restarted your SQL Service.  It would easily cause the problems that you are seeing.  I would take this to GoDaddy.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting this error through your Nagios check.
Make sure you deselect "autoclose" as an option on the database.

You can select the option in: Database properties -> Options
Here select at Auto Close: false